# Redux unwanted effect on .splice()

Tags: reactjs, redux, cart, shopping-cart

**Hello everyone**

Today I'm trying to make a cart with redux and i'm on the step who i have a button for `remove` the product entirely.

If i have 2 products or more in my redux store and i want to remove the first, all the cart will be deleted.

If i remove the last product in all case, the product will be deleted fine.

> That i expect is to remove the product entirely from the cart ( redux store )

This is my cartReducer:

```
export function CartReducer(state = initialCart, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_ACTION':
            const products = [...state[state.length -1].products]
            products.push({...action.payload.data})
            return [...state,  {products}];

        case 'UPDATE_QUANTITY_FROM_CART_ACTION':
            let cart = [...state]
            for (let i = 0; i < cart[cart.length -1].products.length; i++){
                if (cart[cart.length -1].products[i].attributes.id === action.payload.attributeID
                 && cart[cart.length -1].products[i].productID === action.payload.productID){
                    cart[cart.length -1].products[i].attributes.quantity++
                }
            }
            return [...state, ...cart];

        case 'REMOVE_QUANTITY_FROM_CART_ACTION':
            let Cart = [...state]
            for (let i = 0; i < Cart[Cart.length -1].products.length; i++) {
                if (Cart[Cart.length -1].products[i].attributes.id === action.payload.attributeID
                    && Cart[Cart.length -1].products[i].productID === action.payload.productID){
                    const currentQuantity = Cart[Cart.length -1].products[i].attributes.quantity - 1
                    if (currentQuantity === 0){
                        Cart[Cart.length -1].products.splice(i, 1)
                    } else {
                        Cart[Cart.length -1].products[i].attributes.quantity--
                    }
                }
            }
            return [...state, ...Cart];

        case 'TRASH_PRODUCT_FROM_CART_ACTION':
            let basket = [...state]
            for (let i = 0; i < basket[basket.length -1].products.length; i++){
                if (basket[basket.length -1].products[i].productID === action.payload.productID) {
                    basket[basket.length -1].products.splice(i)
                    return [...state, ...basket]
                }
            }
            return [...state, ...basket];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My initial cart:

```js
const initialCart = [
    {
        products: [],
        totalPrice: 0
    },
]
```

The result in my redux store with this `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_ACTION` * 3:

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productID": 14,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 17,
        "price": 24.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "productID": 11,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 13,
        "price": 30.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "productID": 10,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 15,
        "price": 45.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If i remove the latest product with the `TRASH_PRODUCT_FROM_CART_ACTION` * 1:

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productID": 14,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 17,
        "price": 24.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "productID": 11,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 13,
        "price": 30.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see here the latest product as been removed as well:

```json
{
  "productID": 10,
  "attributes": {
    "id": 15,
    "price": 45.9,
    "quantity": 1
  }
}
```

1. But if i remove by example the first element everything will be deleted.
2. Or if i remove the second element, everything in the right in the array of object will be deleted

#### You can see below the unexpected effect :

`first case`:

```json
"products": []
```

`second case`:

```json
"products": [
    {
      "productID": 14,
      "attributes": {
        "id": 17,
        "price": 24.9,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    }
  ]
```

I have try findIndex, my own findIndex with loop, or another indexOf they have the same issue.

Same issue for the `REMOVE_QUANTITY_FROM_CART_ACTION` if the quantity is 0 the product is removed yeah, but they remove another product with it.

Sorry for my very bad english.

Comment: Overall the current code is very hard to read, have you considered using a filter method instead of for looping through it?

Comment: nope i didn't try it because i never use it how can i use ?

Comment: If there's no extra reason why initialCart is an object, I'd suggest using only products as the array. That way you could filter the product away by doing `return products.filter(p => p.productID === action.payload.productID)` in the TRASH_PRODUCT action.

Not sure if it works but could be an easier way to do it. I'd suggest looking into the map function for the other actions.

Comment: I think initialCart can be just an object containing products and totalPrice. There is no need to declare it as an array of objects containing products and totalPrice unless you are maintaining multiple carts. This will help you get rid of the `Cart[Cart.length -1]` part from most of the code. you could just do `Cart.products` to access the items then.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a splice, you're changing the array in place.

From [MDN docs of splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) -

```
If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is equal to or larger than array.length - start 
(that is, if it is equal to or greater than the number of elements left in the array, 
starting at start), then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.
```

So when you do `basket[basket.length -1].products.splice(i)` in `TRASH_PRODUCT_FROM_CART_ACTION`, you are basically removing all the elements in the array starting from i.
You should be doing `basket[basket.length -1].products.splice(i,1)` instead there.

You can run the code below in your browser console to understand what is happening:

```
a = [1,2]
a.splice(0,1)
b = [3,4]
console.log(`a - ${a}`) // a - 2
c = [...a, ...b]
console.log(`c - ${c}`) // c - 2,3,4
d = c.splice(1)
console.log(`d - ${d}`) // d - 3,4
console.log(`c - ${c}`) // c - 2
```

I do not think that reducing the quantity to 0 should remove more than one element going by your code. There, you have rightly used `splice(i,1)`.

Comment: Yeah one product has been removed, but i have another problem is the image are not fetch anymore because react render one more time

Comment: And if i do another action after trash the product every action that i do don't updated anymore the store

Comment: Without debugging, it is difficult to tell why that would be happening. 
And images, I do not think react rendering again is the problem. It is pretty difficult to say anything without seeing what is happening.

Comment: I know i can submit photos if you want, but now time in my country is 01:00 i need to go sleep, if you can come here after i will upload everything you need, goodnight :-) and thank you for the help